# Сокращение кода для вывода массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив array c данными.
Произвожу вывод данных на страницу.
Нужно последовательно вывести все от 0 до 9.
Как мне сократить код, чтоб не писать 10 строк?

```
document.getElementById('data0').innerHTML = array[0];
document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML = array[1];
```

и тд

Comment: вообще, много одинаковых id, отличающихся только числом - плохо) Как минимум потому что задолбаетесь редактировать. Можно им задать один общий класс и достать через querySelectorAll... прогнать через тот же цикл.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.forEach((item, index) => document.getElementById('data' + index).innerHTML = item);
```

---

> У меня этот вывод повторяется 2 раза, но выводит данные только в одну
>   таблицу, а вторая пустая

Потому что у Вас на странице несколько элементов имеют один и тот же `id`. Что в таком случае будут возвращать вызовы `document.getElementById` с одним и тем же параметром? Они будут возвращать один и тот же элемент - первый, найденный на странице, с таким `id`.

Comment: Спасибо. И еще вопрос. У меня этот вывод повторяется 2 раза, но выводит данные только в одну таблицу, а вторая пустая